# How do I refresh a page when clicking on a href? | HTML, CSS

Tags: javascript, html, refresh, href, reload

**What do I have:** 
*HTML, CSS, JS*

**What do I need:**
*Reload a page when clicking on* `<a href>`*.* 
**What do I know:**
*I can reload a page using* `window.location.reload()`*. To use it in HTML code, I have to put it into* `<script>` *tags.*
**What don't I know:**
*How to execute this script code when clicking on* `<a href>`*.*
**My code:**

```
<ul>
    ....
    <a href="#" class="currentpage"><li>About us</li></a>
</ul>
```

**What have I tried:**
*Nothing yet. I have no idea how to link the* `<script>` *with* `<a href>`*.*

Comment: Read my question with more attention. I know how to refresh the page with JS, but I don't know how to link HTML and CSS. I didn't find an answer in the link you linked as well.

Comment: Try:
<a href="javascript:window.location.reload();">Click to refresh the page</a>

Comment: Worked, but it takes more time than it should, for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reload the current page you can use this code:

```html
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction()" class="currentpage"><li>About us</li></a>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  window.location.reload();
}
</script>
```

It will execute the given function after you click on the link.

Comment: This answer needs to attract more attention. No excessive code, just clarified, clear information.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do as below:

```
<a href="javascript:window.location.reload();"><li>Refresh Page</li></a>
```

Comment: Works, but for some reason it takes more time than the marked answer, check it

Comment: because that is being loaded by an explicit function, If you want you can execute it in that way. If still, it will take more time then you should check the order of html page like css, js.

Comment: Try this way:
location.reload(true/false);
If false, the page will be reloaded from the cache, else from the server.

Comment: Still takes a lot of time, like a second

Comment: Did u try this: javascript:window.location.reload(true)

Comment: It takes even more, 3-4 seconds